# How to run more than one task in the background of Visual Studio by using gulp automatically

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am having trouble to run more than one task in the background of Visual Studio automatically without explicitly triggering them each.

From the task runner explorer I can only trigger one watcher to trigger automatically from Binding>Project Open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine your watchers into a single command, using `gulp.parallel`:

```
export const watch = gulp.parallel(watchCss, watchJs, ...);
```